# Highlight new-ish tags on questions

Tags: feature-request, tags

To combat creation of stupid tags ([office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question)...) it would be helpful if new tags were somehow called out when viewing a question.

When reviewing questions, a visual cue for tags that could potentially be groomed would encourage their own hygiene.

Criteria that would apply:

- Tag less than 48 hours old
- No about entry (would need to consider pending edits)
- Low use, esp. single use
- No followers

For users intentionally creating a new tag, the acts of following said tag and/or producing the initial about entry would be sufficient to keep it under the radar.

It would be great if the color was orange, because there's just not enough of that on StackOverflow today!

Comment: Hmm, use the 10K moderator tools to find stoopid new tags, bottom of the page.  Having a peek once a day is plenty, beats getting the orange blast.

Comment: I do that @HansPassant - but many can't. Additionally, that pulls them out of context, which increases the chance of an uninformed decision to delete. On the main tag I follow, there are only 2 regulars with >10K, so the tool isn't available to enough of the community to be effective.

Comment: Nothing could pull them out of context more than a blast of orange offending everybody's eyeballs.  These tags are displayed on a moderator page because it was considered a moderator duty.  Hard to see how it could be related to a "main tag" btw, stoopid tags are not selective.

Comment: @HansPassant Your avatar is orange, did you make it that way to offend everybody's eyeballs?

Comment: Sure.  It is like a canary yellow car, you'll never lose it in an airport parking lot.

Comment: @HansPassant - main tag... Thinking "angularjs" with its ever-growing directive tag-alongs. (See what I did there?;^) Context in this case is both the question the tag has been added to, and the set of possibly-related questions around it (fav list).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new

Comment: @JasonMArcher uh, yeah. It's not that I don't know how to find new tags. Would like to have newish (& potentially garbage) tags be more visible in the context of the question they are on.